# Linq - Conversion error when simulating an exists expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, exists

Im having a problem with Linq using Lambda Expressions. Im trying to do this select

```
SELECT L.IDLLAMADO FROM LLAMADOS L WHERE EXISTS (SELECT D.IDLLAMADO FROM DIAGNOSTICO D WHERE D.DESCRIPCION LIKE '%SOME VALUE%')
```

Some notes:

1. Im using IQueryable because Im appending joins and where depending on
   the parameters of the method.
2. In the example I mapped only a property in my complex class because the rest are not useful in the example.
3. diagonostico is a string parameter.

My code is:

```
DbSet<Llamados> llamados = context.Set<Llamados>();

IQueryable<ComplexLlamadosAfil> query = llamados
.Select(e => new ComplexLlamadosAfil { IdLlamado = e.IdLlamado });

//If some conditions

query = query.Where(e => diagnosticos.Any(d => d.IdLlamado == e.IdLlamado &&
                    d.Descripcion.Contains(diagnostico)) == true);
```

There is not compilation error but when i run this i keep getting this error:

The object type

```
'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[GAMP.MO.VW_DIAGNOSTICOS_LLAMADO]'
```

cannot be converted into

```
'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[GAMP.MO.VW_DIAGNOSTICOS_LLAMADO]'.
```

I also tried using .TakeWhile() instead of .Where() but no success.

Thanks for reading guys,
Pablo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the message is rather clear, no ?

I would do

```
//Don't tell that it's a DbSet<Llamados>. You want an IQueryable<Llamados>
IQueryable<Llamados> llamados = context.Set<Llamados>().AsQueryable();

IQueryable<ComplexLlamadosAfil> query = llamados
.Select(e => new ComplexLlamadosAfil { IdLlamado = e.IdLlamado });

//If some conditions

query = query.Where(e => diagnosticos.Any(d => d.IdLlamado == e.IdLlamado &&
                    d.Descripcion.Contains(diagnostico)) == true);
```

or just use var

```
var llamados = context.Set<Llamados>().AsQueryable();

var query = llamados
.Select(e => new ComplexLlamadosAfil { IdLlamado = e.IdLlamado });

//If some conditions

query = query.Where(e => diagnosticos.Any(d => d.IdLlamado == e.IdLlamado &&
                    d.Descripcion.Contains(diagnostico)) == true);
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasnt the DbSet llamados, it was the DbSet diagnosticos which was declared as dbSet<VW_DIAGNOSTICOS_LLAMADO> diagnosticos and i forgot to copy in the question. Thanks!!